# Receiving two values over serial port using servos

Tags: arduino-uno, processing-lang, java

So I have a java program that picks up the mouses x and y coords on the display and I would like to send those to my arduino and then move my two servos to those locations (I have two servos ontop of each other, one for x and one for y).

The java (processing) code i have is below

```
void draw(){  //same as loop in arduino
  background(52, 152, 219); // background color of window (r, g, b) or (0 to 255)
  //lets give title to our window
  fill(0, 255, 0);               //text color (r, g, b)
  textFont(font);
  text("Ripple Effect Maker", 80, 30);  // ("text", x coordinate, y coordinat)
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 33, 33);
  int x = mouseX;
  int y = mouseY;
  port.write(x+":"+y);
  println(x+":"+y);
  //println("y="+y);
  delay(100);
}
```

I don't have much arduino code because I can't seem to find a way to split the data into two seperate variables and then move the servos to their corresponding variables.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't providing anything to split the data on. You just send the X and y coordinates with a : between X and y. There's nothing between the y and the next X.

By changing the line

```
port.write(x+":"+y);
```

To

```
port.write(x+":"+y+"\n");
```

You then get the linefeed character to split your data on.